# HTML Select Not saving Selected Value

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I am trying to set up a Month, Day input.
To do this I have 2 fields
 **1st:**  A `DropDownList` that allows users to pick a `month`.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="month" runat="server" onchange="refSelect();"></asp:DropDownList>
```

**2nd:** A `select` that allows the user to pick a `day`

```
<select ID="day" runat="server"></select>
```

Whenever the user changes the `month` a JavaScript function updates the days you can pick in the `day` field.
Both the `month` and `day` fields have their options loaded in code behind in `page_load`.
The issue I'm running into is whenever the page is loaded and the `month` field is set to, for example February, and the user changes to another month, January, and selects a day `> 28` the code behind saves the selected day as 1.

```
int test = day.Value; //test will equal 1
```

If the user selects any day `<= 28` the code behind saves whatever they selected. The `JavaScript`:

```
var Months = {
    "January": function () { return 31; },
    "February": function () { return 28; },
    "March": function () { return 31; },
    "April": function () { return 30; },
    "May": function () { return 31; },
    "June": function () { return 30; },
    "July": function () { return 31; },
    "August": function () { return 31; },
    "September": function () { return 30; },
    "October": function () { return 31; },
    "November": function () { return 30; },
    "December": function () { return 31; }
    }
    refSelect: function () {
        var month = document.getElementById("month");
        var day = document.getElementById("day");
        var monthSelected = month.options[month.selectedIndex].text;            
        daysTotal = Months[monthSelected]();
        if (day.options.length > daysTotal) {
            day.options.length = daysTotal;
        }
        else if(day.options.length < daysTotal) {
            while (day.options.length < daysTotal) {
                var option = document.createElement('option');
                option.text = option.value = day.options.length + 1;
                day.add(option);
                day.options[day.options.length] = option;
            }
        }
```

Does anyone know how to prevent this from happening?

Code Behind:

```
//redirects to another page after executing
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int month = (DropDownList)Page.FindControl("month").SelectedValue;
    int day= (HtmlSelect)Page.FindControl("day").Value;

    string monthDay = String.Format("{0}/{1}", month, day);
    User.SaveSelectedDate(monthDay);
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
       LoadDropDowns();
    }
}

private void LoadDropDowns()
{
    string saved = User.GetSavedDate();
    DropDownList month = (DropDownList)Page.FindControl("month");
    HtmlSelect day= (HtmlSelect)Page.FindControl("day");

    string[] split = saved.Split('/');

    DateTime start = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
    for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
    {
        DateTime current = start.AddMonths(j);
        month.Items.Add(new ListItem(String.Format("{0:MMMM}", current), current.Month.ToString()));                    
    } 

    month.SelectedValue = split[0];

    for (int d = 1; d <= DateTime.DaysInMonth(1, Int32.Parse(month.SelectedValue)); d++)
    {
        day.Items.Add(new ListItem(d.ToString(), d.ToString()));
    }

    day.Value = Int32.Parse(split[1]);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code-behind?

Comment: @Crowcoder Added a mockup of what the code behind looks like

Comment: Nothing in Page_Load? Something that maybe should be wrapped in `if(!IsPostBack)` ?

Comment: Have you debugged and seen the values of month and day in the `btnSave_Click` handler? I am trying to find out if the problem is happening in the values being posted or is it just saving incorrectly in the `User.SaveSelectedDate` method

Comment: @Yatin the values pulled from `month` and `day` in `btnSave_Click` are incorrect

Comment: @Crowcoder added a mockup of the page_load method

Comment: @Tylerk, are you sure your code is not throwing any errors. Here's why I am asking: I was trying to create similar code and it gave me error for using `day` variable in the for look in `LoadDropDowns()` as it's already used above it. And, `day.Value = Int32.Parse(split[1])` cannot work because it expects a string.

Comment: And, you can use the names `month` and `day` to access both your lists on the server side code behind. They're server side controls - you don't need to use `FindControl()`. I have created the same application with these things fixed and I am not facing any issue. Correct these things first. If it doesn't fix it, then I may need to see more code to help you fix your issue.

Comment: @Yatin Changed the name of the `day` variable, I switched up the variable names when I wrote this and accidentally included that one twice, the split variable is a string array that splits a string of the form `2/1`, the `2` being the month and the `1` being the day, this string is obtained from the `User.GetSavedDate()` call